# Tile/grid movement in Java (2d game)

Tags: java, tile

I just started game-making. I did follow a tutorial on Youtube from CodeNMore, but I do not like the pixel-based movement system. I wanted to make a grid-based movement system, but I couldn't work out how can I do this.
I am not advanced enough to read some1 else code and understand how it works, that's why i ask you guys!

My tiles are 64x64, so what I do is change `x` value by 64. It doesn't help me because my character starts to teleport all the 64 pixels at once instead of moving smoothly pixel by pixel for 64 pixels (tile size). I tried using for-loops, timers, and thread.sleep, but it didn't really help me.

```
//Activate both of the movement methods. 
public void move() throws InterruptedException {

    if (!checkEntityCollisions(xMove, 0f)) {
        moveX();
    }
    if (!checkEntityCollisions(0f, yMove)) {
        moveY();
    }

    System.out.println("Pos x: " + x + "\n Pos y: " + y);

}

//MOVEMENT METHOD

public void moveX() throws InterruptedException {
    timer += System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (xMove > 0) { // MOVING RIGHT

        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        //Checks for collisions
        if (!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)
                && !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)) {

            //tileSize = 64
            x += tileSize;

        } else {
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x - bounds.width - 1;
        }

    } else if (xMove < 0) { //MOVING LEFT

        int tx = (int) (x + xMove + bounds.x) / Tile.TILEWIDTH;

        if (!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)
                && !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT)) {

            x -= tileSize;

        } else {
            x = tx * Tile.TILEWIDTH + Tile.TILEWIDTH - bounds.x;
        }
    }

}
```

//Graphics code:

```
private Display display;
private int width, height;

public String title;
public boolean running = false;

private Thread thread;

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

//STATES
private State gameState;
private State menuState;

//INPUT
private KeyManager keyManager;

//CAMERA
private GameCamera gameCamera;

//Handler
private Handler handler;

//GAME ENGINE
public Game(String title, int width, int height) {

    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.title = title;
    keyManager = new KeyManager();

}

public void init() {

    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyManager);
    Assets.init();

    gameCamera = new GameCamera(this, 0, 0);
    handler = new Handler(this);

    gameState = new GameState(handler);
    menuState = new MenuState(handler);
    State.setState(gameState);
}

public void tick() {

    keyManager.tick();

    if (State.getState() != null) {
        State.getState().tick();
    }
}

public void render() {

    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    //Clear Screen
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, width);

    //Draw here!
    if (State.getState() != null) {
        State.getState().render(g);
    }

    //End Drawing
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

public void run() {
    init();

    int fps = 60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    while (running) {

        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        lastTime = now;

        if (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            render();
            delta--;
        }

    }
    stop();
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public KeyManager getKeyManager() {
    return keyManager;
}

public GameCamera getGameCamera() {
    return gameCamera;
}

public synchronized void start() {

    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running) {
        return;
    }
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: posting the graphics part of your code is probably more helpful

Comment: I am not sure if that's what you mean, but there it is.

Comment: I'd recommend JavaFX if you want to use animations. Here's a complete game of 2048 I built which has good-looking animations with minimal setup. FX has an easy-to-use API for things like this. Feel free to check out the project or fork it for your own use: https://github.com/prestongarno/2048-FX